# ebay scheduled listing time mismatch

Tags: c#, ebay-api

Creating a schedule listing in ebay from application. while scheduling, application is showing users pc date time and user will give a time relative to his pc time / local time. but while the item is scheduled, the time doesn't remain same.

how to match the scheduled time from local to ebay. **Is it is always posts according to ebay time? or which time?**

if its always posts as in ebay time, then is it the way, to get the difference of now local time and scheduled time and add the difference with ebay now time?

Comment: Do you have any kind of code?

Answer (score 2):

All [dates](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/types/simpleTypes.html#dateTime) in the API request have to be specified in Universal Coordinated Time (UTC). You can allow people to enter a time local to their time zone but you will have to convert them to UTC when sending to eBay to [schedule a listing](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/AddItem.html#Request.Item.ScheduleTime).

For example, a seller based in Japan wants to schedule a listing so that it appears on www.ebay.co.jp at 18:30 Japan Standard Time (i.e UTC+9) on the 25th December 2015. The seller will use the application to enter their local time and date,

```
2015-12-25 18:30 (JST)
```

When your application sends the request to the API it will need to convert the entered local time into UTC,

```
2015-12-25 09:30 (UTC)
```

In the XML this will be formated using the ISO 8601 date and time format.

```
<Item>
  <ScheduleTime>2015-12-25T09:20:00.000Z</ScheduleTime>
</Item>
```

Comment: Ok. So user in japan (UTC+9) will give a time. So do i need to convert the timezone than?

Comment: I've added an example to explain better.